# Пропал перевод при двойном нажатии кнопки тревоги на комментарии

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, комментарии, тревоги

Если кликнуть на значок флажка на комментарии два раза за три секунды, то выскакивает красная надпись, что "загружать окно установки тревоги можно только раз в три секунды". Вот только перевод сбежал, и его надо бы вернуть домой:

[image: дефект]

Comment: Странно, у меня здесь с переводом отображает

Comment: @DiMithras в комментариях перевода нет, в постах - есть.

Comment: Похоже, что у модератора ограничения по времени нет. Можешь проверить наличие перевода? Если ок - поставлю красную метку.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ перевод есть: https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5ZRm.png

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Добавил [переводы](https://ru.traducir.win/filters?key=c4512e9c414296a65de8b323485f02a5).

Будет в новых сборках. Текущая 2023.4.14.43390